# Using command line args from different files in python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I recently discovered (Much to my surprised) you can call command line args in files other than the one that is explicitly called when you enter it.

So, you can run `python file1.py abc` in command line, and use sys.argv[1] to get the string 'abc' from within file2.py or file3.py.

I still feel like this shouldn't work, but I'm glad it does, since it saved me a lot of trouble.

But now I'd really appreciate an answer as to why/how this works. I had assumed that sys.argv[1] would be local to each file.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean ... sys.argv contains the command line arguments when a program was launched ... and its globally available...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the how/why, `sys` is only imported once (when python starts up).  When `sys` is imported, it's `argv` member gets populated with the commandline arguements.  Subsequent `import` statements return the same `sys` module object so no matter where you `import sys` from, you'll always get the same object and therefore `sys.argv` will always be the same list no matter where you reference it in your application.

---

Whether you *should* be doing commandline parsing in more than one place is a different question.  Generally, my answer would be "NO" unless you are only hacking together a script to work for the next 2 or 3 days.  Anything that you expect to last should do all it's parsing up front (probably with a robust argument parser like `argparse`) and pass the data necessary for the various functions/classes to them from it's entry point.

Comment: It would appear I misunderstood how import works. Good to know! Thanks!

This is not a temporary hack, but is only meant to be used internally for debugging. Still, I am going to give argparse a try, as you suggest. I see that it will also let me use flags to specific cmd line args, which would be a useful feature I had not thought of.